# Why did deleting my web/assets folder also delete all source in lib?

Tags: dart, webstorm

I had an assets folder in my web directory and polymer started messing up whatever was in there so I decided to move everything out of it into /web. But then when i deleted the now empty assets folder all the source in my /lib folder disappeared. Is there some link between these that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem in WebStorm / IntelliJ, caused by a limitation of Java on Windows (where WebStorm / IntelliJ are built with).

`pub get` and `pub upgrade` create symlinks to the `packages` directory in `web`, `bin`, `test`, `tool` and any subdirectory of these. 
The `packages` directory contains symlinks to the package directory in `.pub-cache`, and an additional symlink to the `lib` directory of the current package so you can use package imports to the current package.

When a directory is deleted, Java on Windows also deletes symlinked content. **This is why deleting the web directory also purged the `lib` directory.**
The current solution or workaround is, to not delete folders from within WebStorm / IntelliJ.

The Dart team is working on getting rid of the `packages` directory and all related symlinks alltogether. This is already in an experimental state since about a 3/4 year and will hopefully go live soon.

Currently running `pub get` or `pub upgrade` with the `--no-package-symlinks` option, already suppresses the creation of the `packages` directory and symlinks.
AFAIK the `test` is the last part that depends on the `packages` directory. When this is fixed (depends on some changes in the VM) this behave will become the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks Gunter -- is there a way to set it up so that the Pub Get menu options in Webstorm will automatically appentd the --no-packages-symlinks? Thanks.

Comment: A workaround is to replace `pub` with a batch script and add `--no-package-symlinks` when is is called with `get` or `upgrade`. I guess it will become the default soon (no promises though). AFAIK Natalie the maintainer of the test package is currently working on it.